# What does "obsess" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph as follow:

> Knowing what to say to women is the most common concern among males who are unsuccessful with them. They **obsess** over every single word, phrase, and possible response ahead of time. It is an inevitable result of traditional socialization, as it makes males feels inadequate for or intimated by women, while at the same time reducing their natural ability to tolerate uncertainty.

I understand the meaning of word "obsess", but I don't understand it in the paragraph. Can anyone help me? Thank!

Comment: The dictionary definitions seem to apply here. You should add what you found and more specifically what you don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Be obsessing over" vs. "be obsessed with/by"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24061/be-obsessing-over-vs-be-obsessed-with-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informally, the word "obsess" means to think about with preoccupation or unusual focus, in an almost unhealthy context. The paragraph above describes how men often excessively analyze or think about even the smallest words or interactions with women.